# Pythonic way to assign 1 to indices in an 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

What I have:

```
indexes = np.array([[4], [3], [2], [1]])
```

What I want:

```
output = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

So, instead of having a specific number in each index of the input, I want an array with the length of the maximum number (here 4), where the number is the index in the new output.

I can make it work with a for loop:

```
import numpy as np

indexes = np.array([[4], [3], [2], [1]])

one_hot = np.zeros(shape=(indexes.shape[0], np.max(input)))
for i in range(indexes.shape[0]):
    one_hot[i][input[i]] = 1
print(one_hot)
```

But it is rather slow for larger arrays, thus I am looking for a superior approach.

Comment: Your code, as you've pasted it in, can't possibly be what you have, since plain list-of-lists don't have `.shape`, and you're missing one parenthesis too. (And there's an off-by-one error...)

Answer (score 4):

You can use numpy indexing:

```
a = np.array([[4], [3], [2], [1]])

out = np.zeros((len(a), a.max()+1), dtype=int)

out[np.arange(len(a)), a[:, 0]] = 1

out.tolist()
```

Alternatively, using broadcasting:

```
out = (a == np.arange(a.max()+1)).astype(int)

out.tolist()
```

*NB. the conversion to list might be a bottleneck.*

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to create is a 2D array with 1s and 0s perhaps you could try with binary.

```
max_len = 4
indexes = [4, 3, 2, 1]

out = []

for i in indexes:
    bin_val = bin(1 << (max_len-b)) # Binary value with ith bit from the right set. Type: string
    
    lst = list(bin_val[2:].zfill(max_len)) # Force the strings to be max_len (filled with 0s)
    
    out.append(lst)
```

You could simplify all this to

```
max_len = 4
indexes = [4, 3, 2, 1]
out = [ list ( bin (1 << (max_len - i) )[2:].zfill( max_len ) ) for i in indexes ]
```

Both codes should result give the output:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '1', '0'], ['0', '1', '0', '0'], ['1', '0', '0', '0']]
```

Personally I would just work with a 1D array with each element as an integer. The binary representation of that would directly give me another dimension to work in and also make any form of relations / computations easy by using Bit-wise operators.